# PhpMyAdmin error click on Server:localhost link (404 error)

Tags: error-handling, phpmyadmin

Hi I am using MAMP (Mac) and updated to version 2.2. 
In PhpMyAdmin, when I click the link (server:lcalhost) on top left, it throws the error:

"Error in processing request
Error code: 404
Error text: Not found

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Please tell the MAMP team that they have an outdated phpMyAdmin version (3.5.1 ?)

Comment: I updated manually PhpMyAdmin to the most recent version, but the error remains... and some icons don't appear, too.

Comment: I'm encountering this problem as well - I did notice that the upgrade had left several "Mamp" and one "Mamp Pro" directories in my Applications folder, but quitting and relaunching them separately didn't clear up the problem.
My actual databases are still at /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ and the php apps that call them appear to work fine. It's just phpMyAdmin that doesn't see them.

Comment: @Mattia Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: Hi @Geek, my solution was the downgrade ;(

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to directly resolve this. I wound up moving the MAMP folder out of Applications, doing a clean install, and rebuilding my databases from backups. Clicking Localhost still generates the 404 error, but everything seems to work.

I did notice one thing that may be useful: if you go to your Mamp databases from terminal:

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot
(do this before you move them!)

A 'show databases' command didn't show my old databases. But if I put in 'use database NAME', with my proper database names, they did show up in the terminal, and I could run queries as always. This may help you recover your data if you don't have an up to date backup. Or perhaps someone more savvy with databases than I could use that info to re-activate those database in phpMyAdmin.